# Automapper many to many relationship and adding new objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have following models mapped with EF Core:

```
    public class Choice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<ChoicesQuestions> ChoicesQuestions { get; set; }
}

  public class ChoicesQuestions
{
    public int ChoiceId { get; set; }
    public Choice Choice { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}

   public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<ChoicesQuestions> ChoicesQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

and also Resources:

```
    public class ChoiceResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

    public class AddQuestionResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<ChoiceResource> Choices { get; set; }
}
```

I have following mappings:

```
  CreateMap<ChoicesQuestions, ChoiceResource>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.ChoiceId))
            .ForMember(d => d.Content, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Choice.Content));

   CreateMap<ChoiceResource, ChoicesQuestions>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ChoiceId, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(d => d.Choice, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((o, c) =>
    {
        c.Choice = new Choice();
        c.Choice.Content = o.Content;
    });

       CreateMap<AddQuestionResource, Question>()
       .ForMember(o => o.ChoicesQuestions, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Choices));

        CreateMap<Question, AddQuestionResource>();
```

I am using this code in the controller (sending from client addQuestionResource):

```
  var question = _mapper.Map<Question>(addQuestionResource);
```

From the client I am sending the Question with Choices. Now the code works fine, but the problem is, it adds all the time new objects Choices to my database, even if they have the same Content. What I want to achieve is to detect if received Choices exist in the database and if so -> not to create new one, only to add Id of the existing one to many to many relationship. I suppose I should use somehow dbcontext in the MappingProfile class, but I do not know what is the correct approach to these kind of problems. Should I use Automapper at all for this?

Comment: Check AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Does it work with asp.net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because I could not try solution proposed by Lucian (Automapper.Collection), I tried with other approaches. One which works is  implementation of ValueResolver interface:

```
    public class ChoiceResolver : IValueResolver<ChoiceResource, ChoicesQuestions, Choice>
{
    private readonly PollContext _pollContext;
    public ChoiceResolver(PollContext pollContext)
    {
        _pollContext = pollContext;
    }

    public Choice Resolve(ChoiceResource source, ChoicesQuestions destination, Choice destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var choice = _pollContext.Choices.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Content == source.Content);
        if (choice != null)
        {
            return choice;
        }
        else
        {
            var newChoice = new Choice();
            newChoice.Content = source.Content;
            return newChoice;
        }
    }
}
```

and my mapping:

```
    CreateMap<ChoiceResource, ChoicesQuestions >()
            .ForMember(d => d.ChoiceId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.Choice, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ChoiceResolver>());
```

So I solved the problem, the only question I have is if this solution is appropriate in terms of design of web applications and if is any other better approach to this problem?